# how to animate a text flow on top the sectionView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

use: React Native:0.57.1    section list, view,text,animate

I want to animate a text in front of the section View when click on one item of section view.
it suppose to flow a text on top of screen from where I click on the list item to the bottom of screen.

the issue now is that the text looks like animated under the list .

anyone can help is appreciate.

code :

```
import { Text, Button } from "react-native";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Animated, Dimensions, Easing, Image, SectionList, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
// import console = require("console");
// import RegularPicker from "../picker/hkjcPicker";
// import SearchBar from 'react-native-material-design-searchbar';
// import CalendarStrip from 'react-native-calendar-strip';
// import styles from "./styles";
const matchData = require("./matchlist.json");

const matches = matchData.dat;

class CustomButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: this.props.selected,
      bg: true,
      itemCount: 0,
      bounceValue: new Animated.Value(1.0),
      scaleValue: new Animated.Value(1),
      x: new Animated.Value(0),
      y: new Animated.Value(0),
      rotateZ: new Animated.Value(0),
      isDisplayed: false,
      px: 0,
      // selected: false,
      // { selected ,onPressValue} :this.props,  
      py: 0
    };
  }



  // componentDidMount() {
  //   const { selected } = this.props;
  //   this.setState({
  //     selected,   
  //   }); 
  // }

  scaleAnimation() {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(this.state.bounceValue, {
        toValue: 0.6,
        duration: 100
      }),
      Animated.spring(this.state.bounceValue, {
        toValue: 1.0,
        friction: 3,
        tension: 40
      }),
    ]).start();
  }



  onClickAddShoppingCart(x, y) { 

    this.setState(
      {
        isDisplayed: true,
        selected: !this.state.selected
      },
      //alert(event.native)
      () => {
        // NativeModules.UIManager.measure(e.target, (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        //   startX = pageX;
        //   startY = pageY;
        // });



        // let pageX=this.props.onLayout1;
        let startX = 20; // 
        let startY = 50; //  
        let endX = 2; //    
        let endY = 800;  //  


        // let endX = screenWidth / 2 - 32; // 
        // let endY = screenHeight - 160;  / 

        this.state.x.setValue(startX);
        this.state.y.setValue(startY);
        this.state.rotateZ.setValue(0);
        this.state.scaleValue.setValue(1);

        let duration = 3000;
        let endRotateZ = 720;

        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.state.x, {
            toValue: endX,
            duration: duration,
            easing: Easing.linear
          }),
          Animated.timing(this.state.y, {
            toValue: endY,
            duration: duration,
            easing: Easing.cubic
          }),
          // Animated.timing(this.state.rotateZ, {
          //   toValue: endRotateZ,
          //   duration: duration,
          //   easing: Easing.linear
          // }),
          // Animated.timing(this.state.scaleValue, {
          //   toValue: 0.3,
          //   duration: duration,  
          //   easing: Easing.cubic  
          // }),
        ]).start(() => {
          this.setState(
            {

              isDisplayed: false,
              itemCount: ++this.state.itemCount,
              bg: !this.state.bg,
            }, () => {
              this.scaleAnimation();
            }
          );
        });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    const { selected } = this.state;
    //  console.warn("pxy: ",pxy[0]);             
    return (
      <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", backgroundColor: "#ffd505" }}>
        <Text style={{ zIndex: -6, fontSize: 12.5, alignSelf: "center", textAlign: "center", textAlignVertical: "center" }} onPress={(event) => this.onClickAddShoppingCart(event.nativeEvent.pageX, event.nativeEvent.pageY)}>
          {title} </Text>
          {/* Animated window */}
        {
          this.state.isDisplayed ?
            <Animated.View style={{
              position: "absolute",
              left: this.state.x,
              top: this.state.y,
              transform: [
                {
                  rotateZ: this.state.rotateZ.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 360],
                    outputRange: ["0deg", "360deg"]
                  })
                },
                { scale: this.state.scaleValue }
              ],
              zIndex: -1,
            }}>
              <View style={{ zIndex: 99, backgroundColor: "red", height: 43, width: 45, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text style={{ zIndex: 990, height: 40, fontSize: 12.5, textAlignVertical: "center" }}>{this.state.rate_num}</Text>
              </View>
            </Animated.View> : null
        }
      </View>


    );
  }
}

export default class MatchList extends Component {

  matchHeader(matches) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{matches.section.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  matchRow(matches) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.titleLine} >
          <Text style={styles.titleFront}>{matches.item.div}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.dataItem}>{matches.item.rate1_title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.dataItem}>{matches.item.rate2_title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.dataItem}>{matches.item.rate3_title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.dataItem}></Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rowWhole}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.rowFrontTouch}>
            <View style={styles.rowFront}>
              <Text>{matches.item.team1}</Text>
              <Text>{matches.item.team2}</Text>
              <Text>{matches.item.timing + " " + matches.item.pool}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.rowMid}>
              <Text style={{ marginTop: 2, borderBottomColor: "#2b2b2b", borderBottomWidth: 1, backgroundColor: "#ffd505" }}>{matches.item.score1}</Text>
              <Text style={{ marginBottom: 2, backgroundColor: "#ffd505" }}>{matches.item.score2}</Text>
              <Text>       </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <CustomButton title={matches.item.rate1_num} selected={false} />

          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <CustomButton title={matches.item.rate2_num} selected={false} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <CustomButton title={matches.item.rate3_num} selected={false} />
          </TouchableOpacity> 
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.rowImg}>
            {/* <Image source={require('../../../assets/xm.png')} /> */}
            <Text style={{ color: "green" }}>Cat</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  listHeader() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={{ alignItems: "center", }}>
        <Text style={{ color: "green" }}>FootballMatch</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ zIndex:-11 }}>
        <SectionList sections={matches}                            
        contentContainerStyle={{  zIndex:-11  }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          renderSectionHeader={this.matchHeader}   
          renderItem={this.matchRow}                
          // ListHeaderComponent={this.listHeader}    
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}




const itemSize = 80;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
var bg = "#FF9800";


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // container: {
  //   flex: 1,
  //   backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'
  // },
  cellContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  foodView: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#dcdcdc",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: itemSize,
    height: itemSize,
  },
  infoView: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#333",
  },
  price: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#f52328",
    marginTop: 20
  },
  shoppingCart: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
    borderRadius: 35,
    shadowRadius: 8,
    shadowColor: "#aaaaaa",
    shadowOpacity: 0.6,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 3 },
    zIndex: 100,
    position: "absolute",
    left: screenWidth / 2 - 32,
    bottom: 20,
    elevation: 6,
  },
  shoppingButton: {
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  numView: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff9800",
    height: 20,
    minWidth: 20,
    maxWidth: 38,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    elevation: 4,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowColor: "#aaaaaa",
    shadowOpacity: 0.6,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 3 },
  },
  itemCount: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  addCartButton: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 96,
    height: 32,
    borderRadius: 16,
    // backgroundColor: bg,
    elevation: 4,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowColor: "#aaaaaa",
    shadowOpacity: 0.6,
    shadowOffset: { width: 3, height: 3 },
  },
  addCartText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "white"
  },

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: -8
  },
  sectionHeader: {
    paddingTop: 2,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 2,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    backgroundColor: "#3f3f3f",
  },
  item: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    height: 24,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  rowWhole: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
  },
  rowTeam: {
    flex: 9,
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  rowFront: {
    flex: 9,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    alignContent: "center",
  },
  rowFrontTouch: {
    flex: 4.5,
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  rowMid: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignContent: "center"
    // backgroundColor:"green"
  },

  rowRate: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    // backgroundColor: "#d6f7e7" ,  
    marginRight: 3
    // resizeMode:"stretch"
  },

  rowImg: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    // backgroundColor: "#d6f7e7" ,  marginRight:3
    // resizeMode:"stretch"
  },
  rowLast: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    alignContent: "center",
  },
  titleLine: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#3f3f3f",
  },
  titleFront: { flex: 4, color: "white" },
  rowTiming: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  dataItem: { flex: 1, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }
});
```